# Find a line that is the span of some vector $v$ such that the linear transformation does not change any vector on the line

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

The transformation is defined as a matrix multiplied by the vector: $T(v) = Av$

where

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
        .1 & .9 \\
        .9 & .1\\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

I started by computing ${A^-}^{1}$

$${A^-}^{1} = \begin{pmatrix}
        -.125 & 1.125 \\
        1.125 & -.125\\
        \end{pmatrix}$$
but really just got lost after that. I'm not quite sure exactly how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint without eigenvalues.

You want:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{10}&\frac{9}{10}\\
\frac{9}{10}&\frac{1}{10}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y
\end{bmatrix}
$$

so:
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{10}x+\frac{9}{10}y=x\\
\frac{9}{10}x+\frac{1}{10}y=y
\end{cases}
$$
solve this system and you have the equation of the requested line.

Comment: Wow! That was so easy! Sometimes it's too easy to overthink it, I guess. I had $Av=v$ written on the first line, but just didn't accept how useful it was.

Answer (score 1):

The question is asking for $v$ such that $Av=v$.  You are expected to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A$.  $v$ needs to be the eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue $1$ as the equation is $Av=\lambda v$ with $\lambda=1$

Comment: Is there any way to do this without eigenvalues/vectors? We haven't studied those yet. If not, this will answer my question after a few google searches :)

Comment: You don't need the eigenvalue/eigenvector terminology or machinery to still solve $Av=v$ (which is what you want, if you're looking for a vector that remains unchanged by the transformation), this will give you a system of two linear equations. [edit: which is now in _Emilio Novati_'s answer]